# How to construct confidence intervals for causal tree and calculate the actual coverage rate in simulation?

Tags: machine-learning, causality

I‘m reading "Recursive Partitioning for Heterogeneous Causal Effects(Susan Athey & Guido Imbens(2016)" recently， and I'm curious about how do the author construct valid confident intervels for the conditional average treatment effect(cate) and how can we calculate the actual coverage rate if the confidence intervals are constructed? I've tried to

Comment: Have you seen if it is in their code?

Comment: I've read their R package, but I didn't see how they construct the confidence interval.

Comment: ok, I just wanted to make sure you were aware of the availability of the R package. If it is not specified there I unfortunately cannot be of further help since I do not know the details of the paper. Good luck.

Comment: thank you for the same.